# Selenium webdriver: how to verify that there is a heading titled “Download” on the page wrapped in <h2> tags?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, assert

Which assert should I use?  Will you please provide an example?

The code currently opens the selenium website and clicks on the "downloads" link.

On the downloads page there is a h2 heading named Downloads.

```
<h2>Downloads</h2>
```

How can I verify that there is a heading with the text Downloads and that is surrounded by h2 tags?

If I can't add an assert line into the "test" method, will you please help me with figuring out how to create and call the required method within in below code.  I am new to java and selenium.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class guayaki {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.seleniumhq.org/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testGuayaki() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath and `findElements` for this:

```
@Test
public void testGuayaki() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download")).click();

    List<WebElement> downloadHeader = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(), 'Downloads')]"));
    if(downloadHeader.size() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Found h2 header Downloads");
    }
}
```

If you want to perform an exact match, you can modify the xpath as follows:

```
//h2[text() = 'Downloads']
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you!

Note to others: I had to import java.util.List; for this to work

Comment: Richard, what if the h2 on the page was actually Downloadsp.  It seems like this would still pass.  Instead of contains is there something like equals or matches?

Comment: @ChrisStack if you need an exact match:  `//h2[text() = 'Downloads']`